# Laravel routes accepts only specific format

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5.1 and I would like to know if I could only allow specific route format in my routes.php?

The route format should look like this (strict):

```
http://example.com/archive/2015-09
```

Wherein 2015-09 is year-month. It should only accept this format (as stated above). Having a different format will only redirect to the homepage. Example:

```
http://example.com/archive/2015
http://example.com/archive/asd
http://example.com/archive/2015-9
http://example.com/archive/2
http://example.com/archive/2015-09-01
```

So in my routes I have this:

`Route::get('archive/{date}', 'ArchiveController@index');`

I saw on the documentation that [regular expressions could be used](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) but I'm not sure how would I be able to do it.

Answer (score 3):

This is what you want :

```
Route::get('archive/{date}', function(){
    // Your code
})->where(['date' => '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}']);;
```

This will match ...

- Numbers from 0 to 9, exactly four times
- Followed by the hyphen `-`
- Followed by numbers from 0 to 9, exactly two times

Note that this won't guarantee that the date is not something wrong like "9999-99", but you can make those checks in your controller.